# Is there a material that turns from being electrically conductive to non-conductive irreversably upon exposure to some form of radiation?

Tags: conductivity, electromagnetic-radiation

For my project I am looking for a material which can turn from being electrically conductive to nonconductive (has to be irreversible) upon exposure to electromagnetic radiation (say UV). I tried googling for my question but found no relevant answer. A short explanation or a link would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I figure this is the case with most conducting polymers, especially if irradiation is performed in an oxygen environment.